# Elipsis in front of Angular2 Classes (Collections in this case)

Tags: syntax, angular

Why are there in many examples elipsis, or three dots in front of an Angular2 Import.

It doesn't seem to be required, I can remove them and my application will still work. I saw this "pattern" in angular2 examples and in the seed I'm using.

I however would like to understand why this is done, I'm not sure if I'm looking for the wrong phrases because I've tried to look this up multiple times before.

```
providers: [...FORM_PROVIDERS],
directives: [ ...ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
```

seems to be the same as

```
providers: [FORM_PROVIDERS],
directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
```

Is it just for clarifying these are multiple providers/components?

Comment: What you call _ellipsis_ is the ES2015 [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

Comment: `FORM_PROVIDERS `, `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` and others are basically arrays of providers, they're just spread in a new array instance. This allows you to pass a flat array of providers if you add multiple of those.

Comment: @Ludohen Why don't you make it an answer, the Mathijs can accept it and the question is closed. This way it might stay open forever.

Comment: @Ludohen So, that makes sense, I now recall the pattern from other languages. I assume that removing the spread right now might involve bugs in the future, since the code will probably parsing an [[], provider provider] array right now.

Please write an answer I'll; accept it.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer don't know :) ... good point, thanks

Comment: A biit more info: [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/3023-provider-and-directive-arrays-can-be-mixed-depth-in-angular-2-beta-6.htm)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From my comments above.

What you call ellipsis is the ES2015 [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

Otherwise, `FORM_PROVIDERS` , `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` and others are basically arrays of providers, they're just spread in a new array instance. This allows you to pass a flat array of providers if you add multiple of those.

Comment: I haven't seen any mention if it actually makes a difference for Angular2 whether it gets a flat array or an array with a mix of providers and arrays of providers passed. In any case it's not required to make it a flat array.

Comment: That's true, providers can be passed as nested arrays (unlimited depth). It's probably to keep the registry cleaner and avoid unnecessary recursive loops.

Comment: It certainly sounds look good practice, But I just didn't know what the difference was since nothing seemed to change. And finding why was also hard :-)